# Is my solution correct in this case

Tags: future-tense

if you want to talk to me,I am training all afternoon

That was what I answered in a test on future forms but the answer was "will be training"( I am almost sure that my solution is good )Am I right?

https://test-english.com/grammar-points/b1/future-forms/

Comment: People might certainly say that in informal conversation, meaning 'I shall be training' or 'I am scheduled to be training'. However, if the test is about 'future forms' you might have guessed that the more correct future tense was required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normally use present tense to talk about fixed plans in the future:

> We are in Oxford on Tuesday for a wedding

Your sentence is therefore technically correct, but I think most native English speakers would use a future tense. I suspect that the **if** suggests that something might not happen (so maybe it's not a fixed plan), though in this sentence it applies only to **want to talk**, not to the **training all afternoon**.